# Show or hide a element by class when you click a specific link

Tags: javascript, visual-composer

I'm using WPBakery Page Builder for tabs. And I want to show a text block outside the tab section (on a diferent row) with a specific class when first tab with href #1521496635357-e8313acf-e8c2 is open and another text block when the secound tab with href #1521496635380-99d0c08b-67d8 is open (and the first text block to be hidden).

Can you give me a hint with CSS or JS?

Thank you!

```
    <ul class="vc_tta-tabs-list">
    <li class="vc_tta-tab vc_active" data-vc-tab="">
    <a href="#1521496635357-e8313acf-e8c2" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta">
<span class="vc_tta-title-text">PRIX STANDARD</span>
</a>
    </li>
    <li class="vc_tta-tab" data-vc-tab="">
<a href="#1521496635380-99d0c08b-67d8" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta">
<span class="vc_tta-title-text">PRIX BUDGET</span>
</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example is not entirely clear to me, but you should be able to add event listeners to your tabs:

```
<a href="#1521496635357-e8313acf-e8c2" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta" onclick="doSomething()">
```

In your page javascript, you could have a function that does something:

```
function doSomething() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("myclass")[0].style.display = "none";
    document.getElementsByClassName("myotherclass")[0].style.display = "inline";
}
```

You could certainly handle this better by introducing jquery or another framework to simplify some of this handling, but depending on your situation that may or may not be feasible.